# Unhandled Promise rejection: xhr2.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor

Tags: angular, promise, xmlhttprequest

I'm building ASPNetCore + Angular 5 application with Webpack. After upgrade to the Angular5 I get error

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: xhr2.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: xhr2.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
```

what does that mean? (if you need to open the question wider, tell me which files to show)
I apply last stack of errors

```
 at ServerXhr.build (main-client.js:144947)
at Observable._subscribe (main-client.js:46829)
at Observable._trySubscribe (vendor.js:242)
at Observable.subscribe (vendor.js:230)
at scheduleTask (main-client.js:145000)
at Observable._subscribe (main-client.js:145038)
at Observable._trySubscribe (vendor.js:242)
at Observable.subscribe (vendor.js:230)
at Object.subscribeToResult (vendor.js:35030)
at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (vendor.js:64055) TypeError: xhr2.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
```

Comment: The question doesn't even mention if the error happened on server or client side. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr2 is used by Http in server side rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you've solved this already.  However, I just ran into this problem and I had the @angular/platform-server package installed when I was trying to setup angular universal but ended backing that out.  Running the system with the platform-server injects the XHR2 in on the client side of the system.  Removing the import fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, saved me a big time.. :)